# Android get selected text (from WebView and TextView)

Tags: android, webview, clipboard, copy-paste, textselection

I would like some help with getting the selected text from a WebView.

When long clicking a word on a WebView, this word is slected. By pressing copy button on ContextMenu, I'm able to get the selected text with *clipboard.getText().toString();*

However, I would like to be able to get this selected text as soon as the context menu appears, without having to press copy button (or somehow pressing it programatically - by the way, I have looked how to set clipboard manager, but in all examples they show a clipboard beeing filled with a text the programmer already knows, this is not my case, I would like to get the selected text).

**I would like to use it to translate words I don't know by just clicking on them on a WebView (therefore I need to know which word I have selected).**

I have already tried the following projects, without success:

https://github.com/naoak/WebViewMarker
https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2861

In case there is no way to programmatically get this value nor press copy button, personalizing copy button to "GetText" or any other Image or TextView would be enough for me

Thanks in advance!